# Where is NSAlert.h in the iOS  SDK?

Tags: iphone, ios

According to iOS's [Using and Creating Error Objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/CreateCustomizeNSError/CreateCustomizeNSError.html), one can display a error object with the following code.

```
NSError *theError = nil;
BOOL success = [myDoc writeToURL:[self docURL] ofType:@"html" error:&theError];

if (success == NO) {
    // Maybe try to determine cause of error and recover first.
    NSAlert *theAlert = [NSAlert alertWithError:theError];
    [theAlert runModal]; // Ignore return value.
}
```

Unfortunately, I am not smart enough to figure out how to include `NSAlert.h`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: FYI: since iOS 8 UIAlertController supercedes UIAlertView and UIActionSheet.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That document is referring to the (OS X) AppKit framework.  Right after that box, it says:

> (UIAlertView, the UIKit class corresponding to NSAlert, has no equivalent method for alertWithError:.)

You can still use `UIAlertView`, but you'll need to manually populate the title, message, and button strings from the error.

Comment: Thanks. Why does Apple do this crap? Its madenning to someone learning Cocoa Touch.

Answer (score 5):

NSAlert isn't availble in UIKit. the example it just an copy past of the OS X doc.

> This code in Listing 2-1 uses the
>   returned NSError to display an error
>   alert to the user immediately.
>   (UIAlertView, the UIKit class
>   corresponding to NSAlert, has no
>   equivalent method for
>   alertWithError:.) Error objects in the
>   Cocoa domain are always localized and
>   ready to present to users, so they can
>   often be presented without further
>   evaluation.

Comment: Thanks. Why does Apple do this crap? Its madenning to someone learning Cocoa Touch. (Daniel got the green check because he was first to answer - I would have preferred to give both of you guys the credit).

Comment: No prob, First come first serve. But yes the documentation is a bit contradicting some time. Most iOS specific docs are really good, but some of the general documentation about Objective-C are more trailered to OSX.

Answer (score -5):

Its in the AppKit framework. 
[NSAlert](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAlert_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Import that framework to your project in xcode, then use the #include  directive at the top of your code

there are also some samples of using NSAlert if you go to that page and look at the "Sample Code". I always do that if I'm unsure of any part of a new framework

Comment: appkit is not available on iOS