# UIAlertView runModal

Tags: ios, uialertview, uiactionsheet

Followup to [Where is NSAlert.h in the iOS  SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636790/where-is-nsalert-h-in-the-ios-sdk)

Is there any way to get NSAlert runModal like behavior from a UIAlertView?  Or from a UIActionSheet?

I'm planning on using only in debug builds so I'm not concerned with how it looks or if it uses undocumented functionality.

**Edit:**

NSAlert is part of the OS X SDK and is similar to MessageBox in Win32.  It allows you to synchronously prompt the user for something.  Here's an example:

```
NSAlert * myAlert=[[NSAlert alloc] init];
[myAlert setMessgeText:@"This is my alert"];
[myAlert addButtonWithTitle:@"button 1"];
[myAlert addButtonWithTitle:@"button 2"];

switch ([myAlert runModal]) {
  case NSAlertFirstButtonReturn:
    //handle first button
    break;
  case NSAlertSecondButtonReturn:
    //handle second button
    break;
}
```

runModal is a synchronous function, it shows the alert and waits for user response.  Internally it is running a limited version of the message loop, but as far as the rest of my application is concerned, the world has stopped; no messages, no events, nothing.

Comment: Not familiar with `NSAlert`. Perhaps you could explain the behavior?

Comment: so you need to retag this question, nothing to do with iOS, UIAlertView, or UIActionSheet

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Internally it is running a limited version of the message loop, but as far as the rest of my application is concerned, the world has stopped

Just do exactly what you described: throw up the alert, then run the event loop till the alert view gets dismissed. This code works:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
        initWithTitle:@"O rlly?" message:nil delegate:nil
        cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
[alert show];
NSRunLoop *rl = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
NSDate *d;
while ([alert isVisible]) {
    d = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    [rl runUntilDate:d];
    [d release];
}
[alert release];
```

Comment: There's no guard against reentrancy here. If his code re-enters this logic, it will pop another alert.

Comment: Most iOS code is not re-entrant. This solution is sufficient for debugging purposes, which is what OP wanted.

Comment: I had tried something like this previously, `do {[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1]];} while (alertView.visible);`, but sometimes it would get stuck in that loop without the alert ever showing up.  I probably should have included that in the question.

Comment: Is there a way to find out what button was pressed in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to write your own if you want this behavior. Careful, if you block the main queue for too long, your app will be watchdog'd.

UIAlertView gives you modal behavior, and will end up working the same way your custom class will. You might consider using a block-based wrapper that wraps up UIAlertView and allows you to setup blocks for the button action callbacks.