# NSAlert type not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsalert

I am making an iOS application with opencv, so I am writing a lot of code in .mm files.
In .mm file of view controller, I am not able to write NSAlert *alert because it gives an error "NSAlert type not found". All other NSObjects are working fine except for NSAlert. What is a possible reason for this? and how to make it work?

Comment: are you looking for UIAlertView ?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636790/where-is-nsalert-h-in-the-ios-sdk

Comment: Maybe not...  He is talking about OpenCV.

Comment: He's taking about OpenCV, but also about iOS... NSAlert is Cocoa only... On iOS it's UIAlertView...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Volker says, if you're developing for iOS, you want UIAlertView, not NSAlert. NSAlert is a Mac OS class.