# Use of undeclared identifier 'alert'

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am getting an error that says: `Use of undeclared identifier 'alert'`

```
NSAlert *alert = [NSAlert alertWithMessageText: @"Why ? "
                                         defaultButton:@"OK"
                                       ];
```

Can someone tell me why am i getting this error ?

Updated:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it's this line producing the error? Can't see anything wrong here

Comment: I have added a screenshot.

Comment: On iOS use `UIAlertView` instead of `NSAlert`, see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636790/where-is-nsalert-h-in-the-ios-sdk

Comment: On iOS 8, do not use UIAlertView unless you need backward compatibility with iOS 7. Use `UIAlertController` instead. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean

```
UIAlertView *alert
```

Not

```
NSAlert *alert // "NSAlert" does not exist in the Cocoa API.
```

Your clue from the compiler is that it says the type `NSAlert` is undefined. If the type is undefined, then you can get another error about the variable itself being undefined, which is why it says `alert` is undefined.

Comment: That said, those APIs have been deprecated in iOS 8 and people should be using UIAlertController instead.

Comment: You're correct. BTW, can you tell me the purpose of using NSAlert ?

Comment: But `NSAlert` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

For OS 8 & above use UIAlertController & for below use UIAlertview.

```
if(SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"8.0"))
{
    alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"Please enter CVV2 code." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
    txt_CVV2CodeResult.text = @"";
}
else
{
    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Warning:" message:@"Please enter CVV2 code." preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction *OKAction = [UIAlertAction
                               actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"OK action")
                                         style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                       handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                                       {

                                       }];

    [alertController addAction:OKAction];

    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Um... our question asker is using Objective-C, not Swift.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS, you need UIAlertView, not NSAlert. NSAlert is a Mac OS X class.

Refer

[Where is NSAlert.h in the iOS  SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636790/where-is-nsalert-h-in-the-ios-sdk)